При увеличении лимита рекурсии не выводит ответ, как исправить?
Задача сама по себе простая, но почему-то не получается решить
Задача
Алгоритм вычисления функции F(n), где n – натуральное число, задан следующими соотношениями:
F(n) = n, если n ≥ 2025;
F(n) = F(n+1) – F(n+2) + 7, если n < 2025.
Чему равно значение выражения F(15) – F(24)?
Мое решение
from functools import lru_cache
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(2030)

@lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def f(n):
    if n>=2025: return n
    if  n<2025: return (f(n+1) - f(n+2) +7)
print(f(15) - f(25))

Сначала я увеличила лимит рекурсии. Ответ долго не выводился, поэтому попробовала уставить лимит кэша, но сколько бы не устанавливала, выводило ошибку.
Подскажите, как решить эту задачу?

Ну а зачем решать задачу рекурсией, если можно последовательно сверху вниз заполнить список значений?

setrecursionlimit(2 * 2030) - кеширование удваивает требования к глубине стека.
